# GitLab: "Something went wrong during merge pre-receive hook" on WebSite

Tags: git, gitlab

This is my situation:

GitLab:

> -----------develop
>
> |
>
> |------develop-mycompany
>
> |
>
> |--mybranch

I'm trying to merge mybranch into develop-mycompany by merge-request on the website.

It's a rule of my company so I have to do this way.

I haven't aprrobals so I can do the merge request.

**It's the first time that I see this issue. I tried a lot of solutions on internet but don't solve my problem.**

Here a capture:

[image: mygitlab]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: A pre-receive hook will run a script before acting on a `git push`... https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/githooks.txt#L221 This error is saying that something in that script has gone wrong. You'll need to speak to the admin/owner of your git repo to ask them to help you with this as they will be able to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [pre-receive hook](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/githooks.txt#L221)  will run a script before acting on a `git push`

This error is saying that something in that script has gone wrong. You'll need to speak to the admin/owner of your git repo to ask them to help you with this as they will be able to see what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved by just speaking with the admin.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same pre-receive hook when merging my branch into the master.

The reason for this is that my GitLab account name is different from my Linux user name. After setting the same GitLab name with the Linux user name, I merged my branch.

I hope my experience could help you.